# Timedelta method fails to work and states that datetime module does not contain it

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and am trying to work with some datetime columns in a pandas DataFrame. The two variables `'EndDate'` and `'StartDate'` are datetime types and have some negative values when subtracted meaning the data is invalid.

I am attempting to find these offending rows and remove them from the whole dataset and may be going about it the wrong way.

I have attempted to use timedelta to find where the total days equal less than 0 the method does not work in that way.

Does anyone have a way I can do this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Pandas: don't use `datetime` from the standard library, use Pandas objects and methods.

```
# convert series to Pandas datetime if not already done so
date_cols = ['StartDate', 'EndDate']
energy[date_cols] = energy[date_cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')

# construct Boolean mask and filter dataframe
mask = energy['EndDate'] >= energy['StartDate']
energy = energy.loc[mask]
```

Comment: This is very clear and has worked perfectly. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're importing `timedelta`, not the `datetime` module. Just use `timedelta` instead of `datetime.timedelta`. `datetime` in your code refers to the `datetime` ***class*** which you also imported, not the `datetime` module.

When you import `from ... import X`, you refer to it in your code as `X`.
When you just `import Y` (the entire module), you do `Y.Z` to access its members.

Comment: I have tried that but now receive the following: `NameError: name 'days' is not defined` when it clearly states in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html) that it is a parameter

Comment: Yeah, you'll wanna use `timedelta(days=0)` or so, not "days equal or less than 0".

Comment: But surely that is not going to highlight a row with `-343 days`?

Comment: I don't know what you expect `timedelta` to do here. `timedelta` cannot express "less than 0 days", that's not what it does.

Comment: Any suggested way to do this?

Comment: I suspect this is about [tag:pandas] or something? Then no, no idea. Ask a better question specifically about that.